# SELECT many to many tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables:

```
**RUBRIC:** `RubricID, RubricName`

**AUTOR:** `AutorID, FirstName, LastName`

**BOOK:** `BookID, BookName, book_photo`

**BOOKAUTOR:** `BookID, AutorID`

**BOOKRUBRIC:** `BookID, RubricID`
```

I want to write in one SELECT query that return BookName, FirstName, LastName, RubricName.

I have tow separate query but I do not know how to write this in one select.
This is what I got:

```
SELECT book.BookName, autor.FirstName, autor.LastName FROM bookautor JOIN book ON book.BookID=bookautor.BookID JOIN autor on autor.AutorID=bookautor.AutorID;

SELECT rubric.RubricName FROM bookrubric JOIN rubric ON rubric.RubricID=bookrubric.RubricID;
```

It works good but how to write in one select?

I try this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT book.BookName, autor.FirstName, autor.LastName, rubric.RubricName FROM bookautor,bookrubric JOIN book ON book.BookID=bookautor.BookID JOIN autor on autor.AutorID=bookautor.AutorID LEFT JOIN rubric ON rubric.RubricID=bookrubric.RubricID;
```

It returns error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'bookautor.BookID' in 'on clause'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT book.BookName, autor.FirstName, autor.LastName, rubric.RubricName 
FROM bookautor
JOIN book ON book.BookID=bookautor.BookID 
JOIN autor on autor.AutorID=bookautor.AutorID 
left join bookrubric on book.BookID=bookrubric.BookID
LEFT JOIN rubric ON rubric.RubricID=bookrubric.RubricID;
```

Comment: it works, thank you, but can you please if you can explane why 'FROM bookautor' and why LEFT JOIN?